# EntityValidationErrors EF6 Update Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows, entity-framework

I need to update set of records inside a table via entity framework and in a windows service. I have done it normally without any error but now I am getting following error,

**Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.**

When I checked the error the **Nic** which has VARCHAR(12) property is main reason for that. Before I had that **Nic** column with VARCHAR(10) and I updated it to VARCHAR(12). But when I trying to enter a value with string length 12 I am getting that error despite the table and model has set for 12 characters.

Could someone know the reason for that odd behavior?

```
       public void UpdateCustomers()
    {
        try
        {
            CustomerLoyaltyContext newContext = new CustomerLoyaltyContext();
            List<Customer_Update> customers = this.GetUpdatedCustomers();
            foreach (var cu in customers)
            {
                var cst = newContext.Customers.Where(a => a.MembershipNumber == cu.MembershipNumber).FirstOrDefault();
                if (cst != null)
                {
                    cst.MobileNumber = cu.MobileNumber;
                    //updating other records including Nic

                    newContext.Customers.Add(cst);
                    newContext.Entry(cst).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    newContext.SaveChanges();

                    tus.WriteToFile("User by mobile" + "[ " + cu.MobileNumber + " ]" + " Updated : [ " + cu.MembershipNumber + " ]\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    tus.WriteToFile("User by mobile" + "[ " + cu.MobileNumber + " ]" + " not found : [ " + cu.MembershipNumber + " ]\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tus.WriteToFile("Error Occured");
        }
    }
```

My model has,

```
[MaxLength(12)]
public string Nic{get;set;}
```

and My database Nic column has same property also,

I tried following code to my OnModelCreating method but didn't get any better,

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

In creations of records I'm having no issues. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: did you `$ update-database` after changing the model?

Comment: Yes but not in current implementation. My client doesn't allow connect server to internet and doesn't permitted to install third party apps due to security concerns. Therefore I am doing all migrations on my local setup and replace files and whole database in client's server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is due to a mismatch between your database and your model, try updating your EF model and everything should be fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it helps in my local setup. I had to replace hosted server database to my local database after migrated from my local setup. thank you for the reply.